# ESP8266 unwanted delay using client.readStringUntil(), with Microsoft SQL server

Tags: sql-server, esp8266, arduino-esp8266

My goal is to read the number of button press within a period(30s), upload it to a Microsoft SQl table using a php script. On the table, there is another column which adds in accumulated sum of the presses, which will be echo-ed back by the php script, and be read by the ESP8266 board.

So everything went through: I can read the count, upload it, read the accumulated sum back. The issue is it always takes ~5s in order to get a value back from the server. Attached is my troubleshooting:[Serial Windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8JKpR.png)

It takes almost instantly to connect to the server(~100ms) but 5s to read the data that be echo-ed.

My guess was the php script takes time to run to the line where it echo out the value, but same delay(~5s) happens even if I tried a simple script(just echo).

Is this how the server behaves (not giving out the data right away) or is this how Arduino code (client.readStringUntil()) behaves?

Here is my code:

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>

// Wifi Connection config
const char* ssid = "------";
const char* password = "------";

WiFiServer server(80);

IPAddress dbserver(10,1,1,138);  

void setup_wifi() 
{
  delay(10);
  // We start by connecting to a WiFi network
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("WiFi connected");
}

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  // Connect to WiFi network
  setup_wifi();
}

void loop ()
{
  WiFiClient client;
  const int httpPort = 80;
  bool conn = client.connect(dbserver,httpPort);
  if (!conn) {
    Serial.println("connection failed");
    return;
  }
  else {
    // call php script on the server(echo 1 value)
    client.print("GET /test10.php HTTP/1.1");    
    client.println("Host: 10.1.1.138");
    client.println("Connection: close");
    client.println(); // Empty line

    // Read from the server
    Serial.println(millis());       // millis start reading
    unsigned long timeout = millis();
    while (client.available()==0){
    if (millis()-timeout >1000){
      Serial.println(">>> Client Timeout !");
      client.stop();
    }
  }
  Serial.println(millis());         // millis get the data stream
  while (client.available()){
    String line = client.readStringUntil('\r');
    Serial.println(String(millis()) + " >>> "+line);  // millis get each  
                                                      // data line
  }
    delay(10);
    client.stop();    // Closing connection to server
    Serial.println("done");
  }
  delay(30000);
}
```

And is there any other way to fetch the data from the server to an ESP8266 module?

Thank you,
-Danny-

Comment: use the httpclient example routine instead of hand-building http requests; it turns it into a simple sync function call that parses all the headers and whatnot for you.

Answer (score 0):

[SOLVED]: I need to set the Timeout parameter for the readStringUntil() function.

> readStringUntil() is a blocking function. I will wait until it sees a char ('\r' in your case) or the timeout exceeds.

Just need to add client.setTimeout as:

```
WifiClient client;
client.setTimeout(10);
```

Still not sure if this practice is recommended, and how smaller should I go to for timeout?

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be using freeRTOS, and put the webserver in a separate task. 
Then it can wait forever until a request is coming in.